# Play transactions with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I am using Play version 2.2 with Hibernate. I am trying to create another "layer" for managing database operations, do I have to wrap every transaction in this or is there some other more elegant way to do that, I have to make workarounds to access variables passed to method.

```
    JPA.withTransaction(new F.Callback0() {

        @Override
        public void invoke() throws Throwable {
            ...
            JPA.em().persist(someObject);
            ...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the annotation  [@Transactional](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaJPA)

Comment: @Transactional can only be used in Action methods.

Comment: you can add a custom annotation processor and wrap the transactional code.

Answer (score 0):

In this example i'm using aspjectj to wrap methods tagged with a custom annotation to apply JPA transaction : [github example](https://github.com/BenRhouma/Play2JpaTransactions).

- SBT version = 0.13.5
- Play version = 2.2.1

Plugins.sbt

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")

//  Used to weave Logger calls in Controllers and service
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-aspectj" % "0.9.4")
```

build.scala

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAspectj.AspectjKeys.inputs
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAspectj._
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

object Build extends Build {

  val appName = "Interceptor"
  val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion)
    .settings(aspectjSettings: _*)
    .settings(inputs in Aspectj <+= compiledClasses,
      products in Compile <<= products in Aspectj,
      products in Runtime <<= products in Compile)
}
```

Custom Annotation

```
package service;

/**
 * @author z.benrhouma
 * @since 09/09/2014
 */
public @interface STransaction {
}
```

Transaction aspect :

```
package aspects;


import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import play.db.jpa.JPA;
import play.libs.F;

/**
* @author z.benrhouma
* @since 29/03/2014
*/
@Aspect
public class TransactionAspect {

    @Around("execution(* service.*.*(..)) && @annotation(service.STransaction)")
    public Object logAccessRules(final ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
            JPA.withTransaction(new F.Callback0() {
                @Override
                public void invoke() throws Throwable {

                     thisJoinPoint.proceed();
                }
            });
       return null;
    }

}
```

example :

```
package service;

/**
 * @author z.benrhouma
 * @since 09/09/2014
 */

public class TransactionService {

@STransaction // --> this method will be wrapped with JPA.withTransaction
public static  void doSomeProcessing(){
    System.out.println("hello with transaction");
}
public  static void doSomeProcessing2(){
    System.out.println("hello without transaction");
}
}
```